# Rails: hide/close a rendered partial through a button in that partial

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

In my app users render a `_show.html.erb` partial through AJAX. What I want now is to have a button inside that partial that closes it when clicked.

The problem that I have: if I put the button outside the partial everything works fine - I can `.hide()` the partial. However, the button is always visible (what I dont' want). As soon as I put the button inside the partial that gets rendered, closing the partial does not work anymore.

Why is that? What can I do?

**index.html.erb**

```
<div id="show"></div>
```

**show.js.erb**

```
$('#show').html("<%= escape_javascript (render partial: 'recipes/show') %>");
```

**The button**

```
<div class="btn" id="close-show">Close</div>
```

**The JS**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#close-show").click(function(){
    $("#show").hide();
  });
});
```

Comment: can you share the` js` you use for closing the partial?

Comment: ok i added it in my post

Comment: try replacing `$( document ).ready` with `$ ( document ).on("turbolinks:load", function...) `

Comment: This does not have any effect, as in those views I disabled turbolinks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are injecting code to the `dom`, the jQuery event handlers are not bound to the new element . To make it work, you have to use `$(document).on` instead of listening to event directly on the element.
So changing the js to

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click", "#close-show", function(){
    $("#show").hide();
  });
});
```

will do  the trick. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Change your js to as on is bind on future element so it will work even when button is inside your partial.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#close-show").on("click", function(){
    $("#show").hide();
  });
});
```